# list with combination of (string, byte[]) in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make list with combination of (string, byte[]) in c#.net.

I exactly want to store Multiple Images with Name and Image...
Like, List but i don't know how to dynamically store and retrieve data to list!!

store data something like..

```
("Blue hills", byte[]), ("Sunset", byte[]), ("Winter", byte[])
```

Please, help me to operate data something like above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want

```
Dictionary<string, byte[]>
```

if the string value is unique, or

```
List<Tuple<string, byte[]>>
```

if it is not.  Alternatively you could also write your own class to hold the `string` and `byte[]`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

and create a `List` of your class.

```
List<MyClass>
```

Comment: (1)`List<MyImage> Img1 = new List<MyImage>(2);`
(2)`Img1[0].Name = "Img";`
(3)`Img1[0].File = binData;`

I used list as above. but it throw the null reference exception in 2nd line..

Comment: When using `List` you have to add values.  (1) `List<MyImage> Img1 = new List<MyImage>();` (2) `Imag1.Add(new MyImage { Name = "Img", File = binData });`  That will add a new `MyImage` object to the list with the given properties set.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a data structure (e.g. a new class) with precisely those pieces of information. For example:

```
public class Image
{
    private readonly byte[] data;
    private readonly string name;

    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    public Image(string name, byte[] data)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Stream GetDataStream()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(data, false);
    }
}
```

Then you would use a `List<Image>`. Note that I'm using a `MemoryStream` as a useful read-only view of a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use a dictionary. your "Name" seems to be a key:

```
Dictionary<String, Byte[]> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Byte[]>();
```

Then you have the advantaged that you dont Need to iterate, if you want to Access a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Jon said and create a class or use a class called KeyPairValue instead of creating a data structure

Comment: I wouldn't do that unless it was *semantically* a key/value pair, in which case a dictionary would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree, but they've already suggested dictionary, I just wanted to show another option :) Sometimes dictionary won't work (like some serialization cases)